Why are changes to 'changefreq' and 'priority' in SXA not reflecting in the sitemap after publishing?
I am working with Sitecore SXA 10.3 and facing an issue where changes made to the 'changefreq' and 'priority' fields on items are not being reflected in the generated sitemap after publishing. Here are the details of my configuration:
Sitemap Settings: I've configured 'changefreq' to 'daily' and 'priority' to '0.2'.
Caching Configuration: The cache refresh threshold is set to 1 minute, and cache type is 'Stored in file'.
Generate sitemap media items: This is enabled, and the sitemap is configured to generate under specific media items.
Despite these settings, when I update the 'changefreq' and 'priority' fields on a page and publish it, the changes do not appear in the sitemap XML.
Here are the steps I have taken to troubleshoot:

Confirmed that the items are in the final workflow state.
Checked that the event queues are functioning across CM and CD environments.
Cleared relevant caches and rebuilt indexes.

Could someone help identify why these updates are not being reflected in the sitemap? Is there any configuration I might be missing, or is this a known issue with SXA 10.3?


Is that the only change which is not reflecting in Sitemap ? What happens if you add a new page in site, does it reflect in Sitemap ?

@atul When you set sitemap setting as store as file, it is stored under the temp\XA.Sitemap folder of your website root..Can you check there are necessary permission on the temp folder..

Change the cache type to memory and see if the issue still exists

Hello @VikrantPunwatkar , I'm encountering an issue where any new pages I create are not being reflected in the sitemap updates. It seems like the changes are not propagating as expected.

ya can you change the cache type to memory and publish again..as suggested by @RichardSeal as well...

Thank you for your suggestion, @RichardSeal. Changing the cache type worked, and the issue is now resolved.

However, @RichardSeal , may I know why the 'Stored in file' cache type was not working for this scenario?

@AtulGusain Did you checked the permission on the temp folder?
